# Transit visa for Romania

Tags: transit-visas, romania, turkish-citizens

My wife is a Turkish citizen and we are traveling to Bulgaria by air. On the trip home we will have a short 45-minute stopover in Romania.

Does she need to get a transit visa for Romania?

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: no. (I presume 45 minutes mean a single ticket.)

[Do I need a visa to transit the international area of an airport in Romania?](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/30325)

List of the states whose citizens are required airport transit visas:

- Afghanistan
- Bangladesh
- The Democratic Republic of Congo
- Eritrea
- Ethiopia
- Ghana
- Iran
- Iraq
- Nigeria
- Pakistan
- Syria
- Somalia
- Sri Lanka

Comment: Hey the site for the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Romania doesn´t exist anymore :-(.

Answer (score 0):

let me tell you that just for transit ([viza de tranzit](http://vhs-romania.com/main.php?id=transit&lang=ro)) in the airport of Bucharest (Henri Coandă International Airport) like most of the countries, visa is not required.

> The transit
>   visa is granted for up to 10 days (when the applicant travels by car
>   or train) or up to 3 days (when the applicant is traveling by plane)
>   .

Comment: Transit visas are required for nationals of the countries listed in the other answer.

Comment: But if that answer is correct, then so is this one.  The question specifically asked about a Turkish citizen.  It could have been better stated.  Or, since the question was already answered, it could have just as well been left unsaid.

Comment: "Transit visas are required for nationals of the countries listed in the other answer", yes i know **in fact i´m from Romania and i worked at the airport :-)**, so i was wondering why this answer is wrong!. In fact the link that refer "the other answer" doesn´t exits!

Comment: The answer is wrong because it says "for transit in the airport of Bucharest ... visa is not required."  But maybe when you wrote "like most of the countries" you meant to write "for most of the countries"; in that case, the answer would be correct.  Is it a translation problem?