# Do we need an airport transit visa to wait in 3 different airports in Europe, if the final destination is Brazil?

Tags: europe, transit-visas, layovers, filipino-citizens, brazilian-citizens

I am Brazilian and my fiancé is Filipino. We are planning to go to Brazil from Singapore, and the few cheap flights we found have 3 different stops in 3 different European countries: London, Romania, and Portugal. We are only going to wait in these airports for the next flight. Does it require us a transit visa? We won't dispatch any luggage, just bring hand bags with us.

The flight itinerary is **SIN > LGW > OPT > LIS > POA**. This is the image:

[image]

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk (for UK), https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area/30570#30570 (For Schengen) and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91400/transit-visa-for-romania (For Romania)

Comment: Whether you need a visa or not is also influenced by your itinerary - So please add information about your tickets (if booked), concerned airlines and if entire journey is on a single ticket or not?

Comment: @RedBaron, I've added the itinerary.

Comment: @gamofe But is it booked on a single ticket? This is actually crucial.

Comment: You will need to "enter" a country (hence need a visa) if at any point you need to reclaim and recheck your bags. If all the flights are operated by a single airline (or airlines which have interline agreements) your baggage will be transferred without your intervention (this may happen even if on separate tickets). Hence please tell us about airlines and also if the entire trip will be under one ticket.

Comment: @RedBaron, this is the shared link of the flight: https://www.kiwi.com/u/92qg4d.

Comment: Before the link expires: It combines Wizz Air with TAP and Norwegian. It also mentions that some connections are covered by the "kiwi.com guarantee". So this is not a single ticket.

Comment: @DCTLib, what does it mean?

Comment: @gamofe It means that Kiwi.com will sell you three tickets when you purchase the connection. Every airline will only see their ticket and only check you in if they are confident that you meet the requirement to enter the destination country of *their ticket*.

Comment: @RedBaron, since we will not have any baggage with us, do you think we will require to have an airport transit visa for these 3 countries in Europe? This is what is still obscure to me, but by what I understood so far, we will not.

Comment: Skyscanner have a highlightning information about when it is necessary to have visa if required, better than kiwi.

Comment: As a Brazilian national you don't a visa to enter any of your intermediate stops (UK, Romania and Portugal). Your fiancé however does need a visa if she plans to enter these countries. All these airports provide Transit Without Visa (TWOV) for passengers holding onward tickets. As you don't have luggage you don't need to "enter" the countries and can use TWOV. SO theoretically both of you should be fine. However, at each point during boarding airlines staff will check if you have documents to enter the next destination and if they think your fiance does not, she will be denied boarding

Comment: But in the end, the main question wasn't answered. I am aware Brazil and Philippines do not need A visas to transit **in** the airport while waiting for the next flight, but it was told us that if we are in a Schengen zone airport and fly to another Schengen zone airport, it is required. I would like to confirm that.

Comment: There is a website that says when needs or does not need, but it only considers the Schengen country to be the final destination, which is not our case.

Comment: @gamofe None of your stated flights are Schengen to Schengen

Comment: @RedBaron, indeed, I learned later, but still, there will be passport controls and my Filipino fiancé would require a visa, so this is already out of the table.

Answer (score 2):

Your connection seems to consist of three tickets:

- SIN to LGW with Norwegian
- LGW to OTP with Wizz Air
- OPT to POA with TAP

Every airline will see their tickets separately and check that you have the right to enter the destination countries to check you in. Thus, with your connection, you will need to have permission to enter the countries UK, Romania, and Brazil. A visa for Portugal is not required.

You should check the visa/entry requirements for each ticket separately.

The answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/a-b-c-with-2-tickets-several-hours-of-transfer-and-for-b-ill-normally-need) contains further details.

Comment: What permission? The visa? I know that these countries I do not need visas to stay in. The main concern is if it's required to have an airport transit visa for switching airplanes in these airports.

Comment: There is [another question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/a-b-c-with-2-tickets-several-hours-of-transfer-and-for-b-ill-normally-need) on this site which looks at what "kiwi.com guarantted connection" means. You may want to link to it and add a small extract explaining why OP will need to reclaim and recheck his bags

Comment: By the way, we do not intend to dispatch any luggage, just bring a hand baggage with us.

Comment: @gamofe That is an important point which should be added to the question

Comment: @RedBaron, added.

Comment: @gomofe: If you have visa/permission to enter in a country, you can also switch planes in the country. Note that airlines will check that you have permission to enter a country in w hich the ticket that they see ends before you can check in.

Answer (score 1):

For the UK they won't need a visa if they will not go through passport control. If they do, they will need a transit visa.

[If not going through passport control.](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/transit/somewhere_else/no)

[If going through passport control.](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/transit/somewhere_else/yes)

They also won't need one for Romania if you they stay in the international area of the airport. [See here](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/30325)

The only country in the Schengen area a Filipino would need an airside transit visa is France, so Portugal will be fine if they stay airside. [See here](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/annex_7b_atv-national_lists_en.pdf).

So as long as your fiancé stays airside during the connections they will be fine without any transit visas.

Comment: @dda Romania is not a part of Schengen (yet). They accept people with Schengen visas if they have two or more entries. OP will arrive in Portugal (from Romania) on a non-Schengen flight and hence will be controlled on Romanian entry/exit and Portugal entry (if he needs to pass through imiigration)